# Jquery generalise .click

Tags: jquery

I am currently using jquery function(below) to display a block on click of a text. 
can't i generalize it **$('#totalcomments'+id).click** or something , In below code **no** is a integer. basically i have a set of repeating div's whose format is  hiddencomments1, hiddencomments2 ......... So on click on a text whose id=totalcomments1 i want to display the div whose id=hiddencomments1

```
function showcomments(no)
{
 $('#totalcomments'+no).hide();
 $('#hiddencomments'+no).show();
}
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Your best bet is to refactor the html to use a class for "total comments" and "hiddencomments" elements

Comment: io want only that div to be shown and not all divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I've joined the show a little late, but you should **really**, **really**, **really** consider using [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) or [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live)to bind your events instead of [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click).

If, as you said in a comment, you could have up to 9,999 elements to bind this event for, with `click` you're getting each one and binding the same event to each of them; not good. With `live` or `delegate` however, you bind the event **once** to an shared-ancestor of the elements (`document` in the case of `live`), and take advantage of JavaScript's event bubbling mechanism. This is **infinitely** more efficient.

As mentioned by @lonesomeday in the comments, the difference between `live` and `delegate` is the syntax you use to first bind the event; `live` selects the elements to begin with, where-as `delegate` doesn't.

(`delegate` > `live` > `click`)

Whether it's a `id-starts-with` or `class` approach you choose, the notion is still the same:

```
$(document).delegate('[id^=totalcomments]', 'click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#hiddencomments'+this.id.replace('total','hidden')).show();
});
```

or

```
$('.yourSharedClass').live('click', function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#hiddencomments'+ this.id.replace('total','hidden')).show();
});
```

Again, looking at this from a performance point of view, using a class based system would be quicker.

I've done one example using `live` and another with `delegate`, to provide an example of using both.

Comment: `$('[id^=totalcomments]')` on a page with 10000+ elements? That's going to be slow.  This is an excellent example of the advantages of `delegate` over `live`, because it doesn't require an initial, inefficient selection.

Comment: +1 even though I provided my own answer! :) While using `click` would be fine for most things (efficiency isn't usually a problem in JavaScript), `delegate` or `live` is definitely a solution if this is causing a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$('[id^=totalcomments]').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#hiddencomments'+this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0]).show();
});
```

Note that you should be using classes instead, would make your life a bit easier. :)

Comment: +1 for the attribute begins with selector *and* mentioning to use classes

Comment: what is [id^=totalcomments] and this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0])

Comment: `[id^=totalcomments]` gets all elements whose id begins with "totalcomments". `this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0]` uses a regular expression to get the digits from the end of the id.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$('[id^=totalcomments]').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#' + this.id.replace('total','hidden')).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use classes to select them rather than ids?

Answer (score 0):

There are nice ways to do this using the index, depending on your markup.  A more hacky way to to it would be to use the `substr` function on the id:

```
$('.totalcomments').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('#hiddencomments' + this.id.substr(-1)).show();
});
```

NB that this supposes (a) that all your `totalcomments#` elements have a class `totalcomments` and that there are no more than 10 (indexes 0-9).

Comment: @Web Developer Then use regex like Tatu says, which will be accurate but slower. Alternatively, pad them with 0s: `0001` - `9999` and do `substr(-4)`.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this....
first hide all comments

```
 $('#hiddencomments'+no).hide();
```

then show those comment which is being clicked

```
$('#totalcomments'+no).click(function(){
  $('#hiddencomments'+no).show();});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a class, say "visible" on your divs....

```
$('div.visible').bind('click',function(){
  $(this).hide().addClass('hidden');
});

$('div.hidden').bind('click',function(){
  $(this).show().addClass('visible');
});
```

and then you can do styling as well two these two classes.

Comment: i have a lot of divs but if u click on link1 i want div 1 to be shown.Hope i am clear .Anyways can u edit it and explain your code